# How do I make parallel async/unblocking http post calls in java/groovy

Tags: multithreading, jenkins, future, jenkins-groovy

I am having following groovy code which works fine:

```
import okhttp3.Headers;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit ;
import groovy.json.JsonOutput;

import java.io.IOException;

MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data");
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().connectTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.writeTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

  .build();
//MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data");
RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
  .addFormDataPart("request","test.yaml",
    RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG,
    new File("/home/user/test.yaml")))
  .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://mygateway.com")
  .method("POST", body)
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
  .addHeader("Authorization", "token")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

int code = response.code();
def res =response.body().string()
def prettyResponseBody = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(res)
print(prettyResponseBody)
```

How can I make this code to run in parallel in async way? As of now i have list of names of files in list in jenkins, which I am running in parallel but I am not able to run http post code in parallel as i saw as number of request increases time also increase based on increase in requests.So now if i have list of file names with me, how can I run the above code in a async/non blocking way in parallel? Using threading/executor service is out of option because of jenkins limitations.

I am looking some options on Future/CompletableFuture if possible that can run all 7-8 calls in parallel and wait until all completes?How can i do that?

What I tried?

1. Executor service
2. Manually creating four threads, but 1 and 2 dont work in jenkins pipleline
3. I did not tried Gpars, but i tried Jenkins parallel stage, I can store map with callbacks and then say "parallel map" to execute in parallel, then all backend tasks start in parallel the API to upload file using multipart as i mentioned in code, is kind of not wokring in parallel as for 1 request it takes 2 mins, then for 3 request it takes 6 mins and 4 requests 8 min and so on.
4. I did not try Gprs because i tried  jenkins parallel, which is able to make parallel calls to backend as I saw in logs, but this api is kind of blocking.

So i posted only required api, and i am trying in at jenkins-url/script to try some another way to have parallel asyn/non blocking calling.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.  Have you tried GPars
or what Java nowadays offers (e.g. ThreadPoolExecutor)?

Comment: https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/

Comment: added more details.My pipelins is using parallel tag @daggett.but the HTTP upload api ,whose snippet i shared above, is not working in parallel as i see it holds for long time until all requests complete one by one